Walters Ergodic Theory Theorem 2.4: Is this condition necessary?
Theorem 2.4. of Walters' An Introduction to Ergodic Theory reads as follows:
Let $(X_1,\mathbb{B}_1,\mu_1),(X_2,\mathbb{B}_2,\mu_2)$ be probability spaces. Suppose that $V:L^2(m_2)\to L^2(m_1)$ is a bijective linear map such that:

$(Vf,Vg)=(f,g)$ for all $f,g\in L^2(m_2)$.
$V,V^{-1}$ map bounded functions to bounded functions.
$V(fg)=(Vf)(Vg)$ if $f,g$ are bounded.

Then $V$ is induced by an isomorphism $\Phi:(\overline{\mathbb{B}}_2,\overline{m}_2)\to(\overline{\mathbb{B}}_1,\overline{m}_1)$ of measure algebras in the sense that $V_{\chi_\overline{B}}=\chi_{\Phi(\overline{B})}$ for all $\overline{B}\in\overline{\mathbb{B}_2}$.
My question is, is the condition 2 really necessary for the theorem to be true?
I am not sure where in the proof this condition is used. At some point he uses the bounded convergence theorem, but it does not seem that condition 2 is necessary for that as all the functions involved are characteristic functions, so they are automatically bounded by $1$.
